# time series for deep learning modelling

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

What is the best format to feed the input data, which are time series with fixed density over time, to a deep learning network to get minute to minute predictions?
I have a dataset with nd days of entries each one with only 1 minute of interval so we have 1440 entries per each day.
And I want to get nm number of minutes of prediction. To make the things harder i want to every minute update with data of oene minute more.

I tryed this code but only get predictions for 7 minutes and i cant change that:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df = df[[datecname, "Close"]]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,7))
plt.plot(df[datecname], df["Close"])

#Create Sequences of 15 days and predict the price on 16Th day
# [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] -> [16]

#Standardize our data
df["Close"] = (df["Close"] - df["Close"].mean()) / df["Close"].std()

#Train
#Validation
#Test - Never show this one to the model only to make predictions

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_val = train_test_split(df["Close"], test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
x_val, x_test = train_test_split(x_val, test_size=0.4, shuffle=False)


window_size = 15 
batch_size = 32 
shuffle_buffer = x_train.shape[0]

def window_ds(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
    ds= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    ds = ds.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.flat_map(lambda w: w.batch(window_size +1))
    ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda w: (w[:-1], w[-1]))
    ds= ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
    return ds
        

x_train_ds = window_ds(x_train, window_size,batch_size, shuffle_buffer)
x_val_ds = window_ds(x_train, window_size,batch_size, x_val.shape[0])
#dataset de treino e de validaçao criado

#criaçao da rede neural
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[window_size])#primeira camada (de input)
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(input_layer)#primeira camada de DENSE
l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(l0)#segunda camada de DENSE
output_l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(l1)#camada de output

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_l)#passar modelo para o tensorflow

model.compile(optimizer="RMSprop", 
             loss="mse",
             metrics="mse")#Aqui omodelo é3 compilado

model.fit(x_train_ds, validation_data=x_val_ds, epochs=100)#Nesta linha o modelo é treinado

x_test = x_test.to_numpy

#célula de teste de modelo
forecast = []
buys = {}
sells = {}

for i in range(0, len(x_test()) - window_size, window_size):

    f = model.predict(x_test[i:i+window_size][np.newaxis])[0][0]

    if f > x_test[window_size]:
        buys.update({i+window_size:x_test[i+window_size]})
    elif f < x_test[window_size]:
        sells.update({i+window_size:x_test[i+window_size]})

    

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
plt.plot(x_test(), label="Price")
plt.plot(forecast, label="")
plt.plot(list(buys.keys()), list(buys.values()), "^", color="g", label="Buy")
plt.plot(list(sells.keys()), list(sells.values()), "v", color="r", label="Sell")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
```

Comment: TF tutorial could be relevant [Time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series).

Comment: I'm in doubt how to adapt my model to predict any number of minutes.